# Read PublicAccess property for AzureRmStorageAccount

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

I'm trying to read the current state of the Azure Storage Accounts that are returned by
`Get-AzureRmStorageAccount`.
The block looks like

```
    foreach($a in $accounts){
       $context = $a.Context
       $containers += Get-AzureStorageContainer -Context $context
       Write-Output($containers)
    }
```

Right now this spits out the error `The client ... does not have authorization to perform action` blah blah. This is fine since I don't need to access anything inside. This does also however produce an output of

```
CloudBlobContainer : Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob.CloudBlobContainer
Permission         : Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob.BlobContainerPermissions
PublicAccess       : Off
LastModified       : 
ContinuationToken  :
Context            : Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Commands.Storage.AzureStorageContext
Name               : somename
```

I just want to read all of those PublicAccess fields

Comment: Looks the `PublicAccess` has been returned, it is `Off` in your case, which means `Private`. Any concern?

Comment: When I read your comment I immediately realized that what I was looking for had been returned, it was just a parsing issue. I'm feeling silly about that. Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's your concern?

If you only want the public access, it's already show there.

If you concern the error, would you please give following information for investigation:

1. Which line of the script report the error?
2. the Error details (hide any credential)
3. Storage module version (get by run "Get-module" after the error repro)
4. Run "$Error[0].Exception.ToString()" after after the error repro, and give the output.

Besides that, the formal way for Azure Powershell issue is open an issue in https://github.com/Azure/azure-powershell/issues. If you follow the issue template, most of the necessary information for investigation will be there.

Comment: No, you're right. The answer was staring me right in the face. It was doing what I wanted but the output was sometimes getting buried in the error message. I just needed to move the Write-Output statement. The error message itself is to do with permissions, which is fine.